# What is the syntax for creating a Dictionary with values as instances of Action<T>?

Tags: c#, generics

I need to create a Dictionary object as a member field
key = string
value = an instance of `Action<T>` where T could be different per entry, e.g. long, int, string (a ValueType or a RefType)

However can't get the compiler to agree with me here.. To create a member field it seems to need a fixed T specification. I've passed my limit of struggle time before awareness that 'It shouldn't be this difficult'

Might be a generics noob mistake. Please enlighten..

The usage would be something like this

```
m_Map.Add("Key1", 
   new delegate(long l) {Console.Writeline("Woohoo !{0}", l.ToString();));
```

Comment: (re comment) boxing isn't as bad as you might think. In particular, boxing will be *vastly* faster than dynamic-invoke, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, basically. How would the compiler know what type you were interested in for any particular entry?

You can't even explain a relationship of `Dictionary<Type, Action<T>>` where each dictionary entry has a key which is a type and an action which uses that type. Generics just doesn't support that relationship.

If you *will* know the kind when you try to use it, you can just make it a `Dictionary<string, Delegate>` and cast the value when you fetch it. Alternatively, you could use `Action<object>` and live with the boxing and cast you'll end up with.

Note that to use anonymous methods or lambda expressions with just `Delegate`, you'll need to cast - or write a handy conversion method:

```
public static Delegate ConvertAction<T>(Action<T> action)
{
    return action;
}
```

That way you can write:

```
Delegate dlg = ConvertAction((long x) => Console.WriteLine("Got {0}", x));
```

or in the dictionary context:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
dict["Key1"] = ConvertAction((long x) => Console.WriteLine("Got {0}", x));
```

You'll still need to cast to the right type when you fetch the value out of the dictionary again though...

**A different tack...**

Instead of exposing a dictionary directly, you could encapsulate the dictionary in your own type, and have a generic `Add` method:

```
public void Add<T>(string key, Action<T> action)
```

So it would still be a `Dictionary<string, Delegate>` behind the scenes, but your type would make sure that it only contained values which were delegates taking a single argument.

Comment: Tried that however get a compile-error: "Can't cast anonymous method to type Delegate"...

Comment: The only thing that I'm trying to enforce here is that the value should be a method that takes one parameter.

Comment: Edited to account for this. (See the bottom.)

Comment: I ended doing a variation of what you too proposed.. worked. Just needed your tip of having to jump via an extra method to convert the Action<T> to a Delegate. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With different `T` per entry, perhaps standardise at `Action<object>`, and cast inside the actual actions?

```
    static void Main() {
        var m_Map = new Dictionary<string, Action<object>>();
        m_Map.Add("Key1", obj => Console.WriteLine("Woohoo !{0}", obj));
        m_Map.Add("Key2", obj => SomeMethod((int)obj));

        m_Map["Key1"](123);
        m_Map["Key2"](123);
    }
    static void SomeMethod(int i) {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod: {0}", i);
    }
```

Comment: and box-unbox my value-types in these generic times.. Sacrilege! :) I must confess that I did think of that in one of my weaker moments whilst I was struggling to get this to work.

Comment: +1 for making me benchmark :)
[.03 seconds. GC Collections =   3 for Action<object>.Invoke]  [2.81 seconds. GC Collections =  70 for Delegate.DynamicInvoke]  [.03 seconds. GC Collections =   0 for Action<T>.Invoke]
Was surprised that Action<object> runs as fast as Action<T> - but obviously leads to more boxes and casts in code. A snippet of what I needed it for is posted in my resp to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805505/c-marking-class-property-as-dirty/