# Mark object (not entity, not framework) as dirty in WPF ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand, canexecute

In my viewmodel, there is a property `CurrentObject` of the type `SomeDomainType` which is serializeable.

There is a form to edit its properties, and one of the buttons is "Commit Changes", databound to the ICommand `CommitChangesCommand`.

Now I expect this button to be active (via `CanCommitChangesCommand()`, properly wired with Josh Smith's `RelayCommand`) only when the object has been modified, that is, the object is "dirty".

Saying it again, what I want to ask is:

> "How can I mark an object as dirty so that I could have a `private bool ThatPropertyIsDirty()` method to check that inside some `CanExecute()`?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sound of it:

1. Add a `IsDirty` property onto your `SomeDomainType`
2. In the setter of `IsDirty` raise the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event for `IsDirty`
3. In all of the properties on your `SomeDomainType` that you change to make the object considered `Dirty`, in their setters, set `IsDirty` to true

This is presuming your `SomeDomainType` implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. If not, create a wrapper class around the `SomeDomainType` that does, and make the above changes to that wrapper.

Comment: Interesting. Would you say there is a typical situation where the object is considered "clean" again, for example, just after it is persisted? Should `IsDirty` property be public then? I'm very beginner in dealing with object persistence (by the way, my type implements `[Serializable]`, but I chose not to implement `INPC` on it so far).

Comment: Yes, usually after your object is persisted to whatever persistence method you're using (db, flat files etc), then it's considered clean, and you'll want to set `IsDirty` to false.
You'll probably want to expose `IsDirty` as public, with a private setter, as nothing needs to set it dirty, aside from the properties themselves.

Comment: That seems ok. Just for the record, I think I'll combine your tips with the `StatusEnum` proposed in this question (best for transaction entities, I guess). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805505/c-sharp-marking-class-property-as-dirty

Comment: No problem, whatever works for your scenario, if you need that level of distinction in your class then go for it.